Terraform - can't attach S3 access to lambda
I'm trying to create multiple lambda functions with S3 bucket access with Terraform. The terraform script runs fine but lambda function still don't have S3 access. In lambda web UI, under Configuration - Permissions - Resource Summary - By resource, my lambda functions only have access to logs.
How to fix this? Thank you.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }

    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = var.region
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "this" {}

data "aws_ecr_authorization_token" "token" {}

provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address  = format("%v.dkr.ecr.%v.amazonaws.com", data.aws_caller_identity.this.account_id, var.region)
    username = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.user_name
    password = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.password
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_execution_role" {
  name = "lambda_execution_role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole",
        Principal = {
          Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Effect = "Allow",
        Sid = ""
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_s3_access" {
  name = "lambda_s3_access_policy"
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:PutObject",
          "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        Resource = [
          "arn:aws:s3:::mys3bucketname/*"
        ],
        Effect = "Allow"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_s3_access_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_s3_access.arn
}

module "lambda_proxy" {
  source         = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  count          = var.num_proxies
  function_name  = "proxy-${count.index}"
  create_package = false
  image_uri      = module.docker_image.image_uri
  package_type   = "Image"
  architectures  = ["x86_64"]
  timeout        = 30
  hash_extra     = count.index
  lambda_role    = aws_iam_role.lambda_execution_role.arn
}

module "docker_image" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws//modules/docker-build"
  create_ecr_repo = true
  ecr_repo        = "lambda-proxy"
  source_path     = "${path.module}/src"
  platform        = "linux/amd64"

  image_tag = sha1(join("", [
    filesha1("${path.module}/src/requirements.txt"),
    filesha1("${path.module}/src/lambda_function.py"),
    filesha1("${path.module}/Dockerfile")
  ]))

  ecr_repo_lifecycle_policy = jsonencode({
    "rules" : [
      {
        "rulePriority" : 1,
        "description" : "Keep only the last 1 image",
        "selection" : {
          "tagStatus" : "any",
          "countType" : "imageCountMoreThan",
          "countNumber" : 1
        },
        "action" : {
          "type" : "expire"
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}


It turns out that role in module is bit different. The following config works.
module "lambda_proxy" {
  source         = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  count          = var.num_proxies
  function_name  = "proxy-${count.index}"
  create_package = false
  image_uri      = module.docker_image.image_uri
  package_type   = "Image"
  architectures  = ["x86_64"]
  timeout        = 30
  hash_extra     = count.index
  attach_policy = true
  policy        = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
}

